# Change image to text on hover

Tags: html, css

How do I make an image change to text when hovered, and back again when the mouse leaves using HTML, CSS and JavaScript? I am currently using [HTML5UP's Aerial theme](http://html5up.net/aerial) if that makes any difference.

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS code (jsfiddle)

Comment: you can by placing your image as background in css and put another one in the css for your hover but i cant tell you anything more as you did not put your code here

Comment: What image you want to change? the background? I also use that template for other projects, but if you don't give us ***your*** code and what you tried to do, it's very difficult to guess how to help you.

Comment: I want to change the "Spydar007" logo image from to a h1 tag with a fade. See [spydar007.com](http://spydar007.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just css:

```css
#logo-holder {position:relative; width:992px; height:125px; /*dimensions of image*/}
#logo-holder .image,
#logo-holder .text {transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;}
#logo-holder .text {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; opacity:0;}

#logo-holder:hover .image {opacity:0;}
#logo-holder:hover .text {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div id="logo-holder">
    <img src="http://spydar007.com/images/logo.png" class="image" />
    <div class="text">Show this text on hover</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! With minor modification I was able to get it to work (because the image was off-center).

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a quick and dirty solution, and I have no idea if it is actually what you are looking for, you were extremely vague.

http://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/WvOdRw

Essentially, the text is always there but hidden using `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden`. This allows us to do a nice transition to get the text to appear.

Biggest plus point, no JS used at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code it really helpful

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" >
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CSS3 hover text animate in div</title>
        
        <style>
        .c--anim-btn span {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        }
        
        .c--anim-btn, .c-anim-btn {
        transition: 0.3s;   
        }
        
        .c--anim-btn {
        height: 64px;
        font: normal normal 700 1.2em/4em Arial,sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        
        }
        
        .c-anim-btn{
        margin-top: 0em; 
        }
        
        .c--anim-btn:hover .c-anim-btn{
        margin-top: -4em;
        }
        </style>
        
        </head>
        <body>
        <!-- HINT: hover over button -->
        <div class="c--anim-btn">
        <span class="c-anim-btn">
        Hover Here
        </span>
        <span>
        <a href="http://sanwebcorner.com"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZFCnUdrABLc/VlMOOwRCNeI/AAAAAAAAA9g/O5-y5ySNyLc/s1600-r/Copy%2Bof%2Bsan-02%2Bcopy.png" style="    height: 35px;
        margin-top: 15px;"></a>
        </span>
        </div>
        <h2><a href="http://sanwebcorner.com">www.sanwebcorner.com</a></h2>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Here is the [reference](http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2018/11/On-Hover-Change-text-to-image-using-simple-css-code.html)