# Css on mouse over change from image to text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Was looking into this issue for more than an hour, need your help guys, nothing I could find on internet. I want that when on mouse over the image changed to text like "home" and on mouse out it would change back to the image. **But the webpage has multiple links on nav bar for example - Home/About/Contact...**

```css
nav {
  font-size: 40px;
}

nav:hover {
  content: "home"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-home"></a>
    </nav>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change image to text on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785038/change-image-to-text-on-hover)

Comment: Your question does not include enough sample code to demonstrate what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nav:hover::after` as the selector for the text (i.e. a pseudo-element), with `position: absolute` and a white background to cover/hide the icon (and `position: relative` on the `nav` element itself to make it the anchor for the absolute position)

```css
nav {
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

nav:hover:after {
  content: "home";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-home"></a>
  </nav>


</body>
```

Comment: But what if i have multiple nav elements ? For example - Home/About/Contact etc.. If I would add <span> after every <a> when on mouseover - it would all show the text. But I want to do it one by one

Comment: well, apply IDs or classes to your single nav elements and use those IDs in the same way I used `nav` in my answer (multiple times) (or use `: nth-child` selectors if you can't change the HTML code)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler and cleaner approach to the task: it involves showing and hiding different elements instead to edit an element type and format on runtime:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-home"></a>
      <span>text</span>
    </nav>


  </body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  font-size: 40px;
}

nav span {
  display: none;
}

nav:hover a {
 display: none;
}

nav:hover span {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b2ycwjtu/

Comment: But what if i have multiple nav elements ? For example - Home/About/Contact etc..
If I would add <span> after every <a> when on mouseover - it would all show the text. But I want to do it one by one

Comment: Multiple elements behave the same by css, values are in the scaffolding so your scaffolding data is not influenced by css. Separation of concerns apply also in html/css area. By css you can define different behaviour adding classes or css paths.

Answer (score 0):

by the way... ?

```css
nav { font-size: 40px }
nav span { display: none }
nav:hover span { display:inline }
```

```html
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<nav>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-home"></a>
  <span>HOME</span>
</nav>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can probably tell CSS is the way to go for this, but that being said if you *wanted* to do it with javascript you could use something like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image/Text Switching</title>
</head>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Image/Text Switching
    </h1>
    <div>    
    <div id="container">
        <img id="imgToReplace" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
        <div id="textContainer"></div>
    </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var replacementText = "Home";

var imgElement =  document.getElementById('imgToReplace');
var textContent = document.createTextNode(replacementText);
var textContainer = document.getElementById('textContainer');
var container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    imgElement.style.display = "none";
  textContainer.appendChild(textContent); 
});
container.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    imgElement.style.display = "unset";
    textContainer.innerHTML = "";
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

One caveat with this approach is that the #textContainer element and the #imgToReplace element must be the same height and width. If you do decide to go this route maybe use some js to set the height and width of the created #textContainer element.

The fiddle can be found [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/jand524m/18/)